# Codeception: [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::wait

Tags: laravel, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm making my first acceptance test with Codeception.

When I run my test with `wait()` or `waitForElement()`, I get this message:

```
[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::wait
```

Here is my `acceptance.yml`

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for acceptance tests.
# Perform tests in browser using the WebDriver or PhpBrowser.
# If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate     suite.

class_name: WebGuy
modules:
enabled:
    - WebDriver
    - \Helper\Acceptance
config:
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://rh.dev'
        browser: 'firefox'
```

And here is my test:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Register my profile for the first time');
$I->amOnPage('/register');
$I->fillField('name', $person->name);
$I->wait(3); // secs
$I->fillField('lastName', $person->lastName);
```

I got it from  [official doc](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#.VuxkRBLhDVo)

I also made sure to execute:

```
vendor/bin/codecept build
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Your configuration file declares WebGuy and uses Codeception 2.0 (or earlier) configuration style, but AcceptanceTester is used in your test.  They are not related.

Comment: I don t understand. I m new to codecption. Can you please detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `class_name: WebGuy` to `class_name: AcceptanceTester`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with the missing `wait()` method. The problem was I was using `PhpBrowser` instead of `WebDriver`, and `PhpBrowser` doesn't provide that method. It is trivial to implement it yourself in your tester class:

```
public function wait($seconds) {
    sleep($seconds);
}
```

Comment: It is better to make it to do nothing, because your function makes test take X seconds longer for no good reason.

Comment: @Naktibalda Why are you sure that I don't have a good reason? I may be waiting for my test mail server to transfer an email, for example. I may be waiting for anything that happens outside the browser.

Comment: wait() in WebDriver is for delayed effects in the browser. There are no such effects when PhpBrowser is used. It would be better to use a different method name when you actually need to wait in both modules.