# wait() calls an RuntimeException error codeception

Tags: php, selenium, automation, automated-tests, codeception

Writing a small test for my website. However, my browser works way to slow for my test so I need a short 'timeout' while everything loads there. I tried to used .wait(secs), but I receive an error:

> [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::wait

Here's everything what I got from my code:

```
class LoginCest
{

public function successFirstTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
$I->wantTo("Create test case for login");
        $I->amOnPage('link');
//        $I->wait(5); 
        $I->see("wow");
        $I->fillField("//input[@name='userIdentifier']", 'myEmail');
        $I->click("//button[contains(text(),'Prisijungti')]");
        $I->wait(10);
        $I->see("thEText");
}
}
```

yml file: [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093658/codeception-runtimeexception-call-to-undefined-method-acceptancetesterwait

Comment: Still receiving an error. Updated my post with more pictures

Comment: @VaheShak I've tried to change class_name to same as .php class,but still received same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using waitForText() instead of wait()?

Comment: Yea I've tried, received: 
[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::waitForText..
As I understand those functions should work by default,no?

Comment: Delete `class_name` setting, it is an old name od `actor` setting, so don't mess with it without a good reason. The value should be `AcceptanceTester`.